# Python vigenere doesn't accept spaces

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, cycle, python-itertools, vigenere

I have written a python vigenere cipher and it wouldn't accept spaces so I added some code and now it doesn't print the correct output.

If the input is, 'computing is fun' and the keyword is 'gcse', the output should be 'jrfubwbsn ll kbq'. In my program the output is 'jrfubwbsn bx ins'.

Here is how a [vigenere cipher](http://science.howstuffworks.com/code-breaker3.htm) should work.

The code is below:

```
from itertools import cycle

print("NOTE: The program does not encrpyt/decrypt numbers or ASCII characters. These include punctuation marks. Trying to encrypt/decrypt these values will print an error and you will have to try again.\n")

def main():
    def encrypt():
        boolean = False
        while boolean == False:
            message = str(input("Input a message: "))
            keyword = input("Keyword: ")
            if message.isdigit() == True or keyword.isdigit() == True:
                print("Invalid data type! Please try again.\n")
            else:
                boolean = True

        keystream = cycle(keyword)
        encrypted_msg = ''
        for msg, key in zip(message, keystream):
            spaceChar = 0
            newMsg = ord(msg)
            newKey = ord(key)

            switch = True
            if newMsg == 32:
                encrypted_msg += " "
                switch = False
            else:
                pass

            if switch == True:
                if 64 < newMsg < 91:
                    newMsg -= 64
                elif 96 < newMsg < 123:
                    newMsg -= 96
                else:
                    pass

                if 64 < newKey < 91:
                    newKey -= 64
                elif 96 < newKey < 123:
                    newKey -= 96
                else:
                    pass

                newChar = newMsg + newKey + 96


                if newChar > 122:
                    newChar = newChar - 26
                elif 96 > newChar > 91:
                    newChar -= 26

                encrypted_msg += chr(newChar)
            else:
                pass



        print("Encrypted message: %s" %encrypted_msg)

    def decrypt():
        boolean = False
        while boolean == False:
            message = str(input("Input a message: "))
            keyword = input("Keyword: ")
            if message.isalpha() == True or keyword.isalpha() == True:
                boolean = True
            elif message.isalpha() == False:
                print("Invalid data type! Please try again.\n")
            else:
                pass

        keystream = cycle(keyword)
        decrypted_msg = ''
        for msg, key in zip(message, keystream):
            newMsg = ord(msg)
            newKey = ord(key)

            if 64 < newMsg < 91:
                newMsg -= 64
            elif 96 < newMsg < 123:
                newMsg -= 96
            else:
                pass

            if 64 < newKey < 91:
                newKey -= 64
            elif 96 < newKey < 123:
                newKey -= 96
            else:
                pass

            newMsg = ord(msg) - 96
            newKey = ord(key) - 96
            newChar = newMsg - newKey + 96


            if newChar > 122:
                newChar = newChar - 26
            elif 96 > newChar > 91:
                newChar -= 26


            decrypted_msg += chr(newChar)

        print("Decrypted message: %s" %decrypted_msg)

    def task2choice():
        boolean = False
        while boolean == False:
            choice = str(input("Encrypt or Decrypt. [e/d]: "))
            print(" ")
            if choice.lower() == 'e' or choice.lower() == 'd':
                boolean = True
            else:
                print("Please select 'e' or 'd'.")
        if choice.lower() == 'e':
            encrypt()
        elif choice.lower() == 'd':
            decrypt()
        else:
            pass
        print(' ')
    task2choice()

def again():
    again = input("Would you like to restart? [y/n]: ")
    return again.lower() == 'y'


while main() or again():
    pass
```

The problem occurs because when the for loop checks for the space and skips a letter in the keyword.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should reconsider using `zip` - just get the `next` key as needed. Good use of iterators, though!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks but I have used zip. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could remove the spaces *before* zipping the string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The output needs to have spaces in it.

Comment: Then you have to stop using `zip`. Or insert matching characters for the spaces into the key, which would be much more difficult.